# How do I correctly use Maven with versioning?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

Currently I'm in the transition of moving ANT projects to Maven and struggling on how to get the project versioning working correctly. Currently I have about 30+ projects/modules that all rely on each other so everything must be at the latest version to work correctly. This was easily done with ANT but when it comes to Maven I would need to make constant changes to all other released project POM's to allow them to pick up these new changes.

I discussed with a few other developers and we decided we might not even need a maven repo with version numbers, we just have everything at the same version number and build locally or through Jenkins to update our .m2 folders. Does this sound like the correct route for our situation? Are we missing anything doing this?

I did suggest having our test Jenkins to deploy to a repo with version numbers like 1.0.Beta-SNAPSHOT. We have Jenkins setup to build when our testing branches are updated. This means I would not have to locally compile every project on that branch to update my .m2, I could just change the POM to pull all these Beta-SNAPSHOT versions in one place. Would there be a good way for me to do this that would not affect the release if it was pushed and released with this version number set? If I wanted to use my local versions I would then just switch this version number to 1.0.0 which isn't within the repo but my local .m2.

Any suggestions on how to properly manage the maven projects/modules with version numbers would be welcome! Something that reduces the need to change every POM when releasing 1 of the projects/modules would be best!

Answer (score 1):

Our developer struggle with this problem a lot. It is a lot of manual work to update all the POMs for a release.

We are going to aim for multi-module projects, which also seems like a good fit for you.

If you say, that everything must be using the latest versions all the time, I would put all the projects into one large multi-module project. This means that you have one (git) repository with a main POM in the root directory and a directory for each module (sub-project) with its own POM references the main POM as parent.

Then you can run `mvn clean install` on the parent and build *all* the modules with consistent version numbers. So releasing is then just one large build.

You should note, though, that you tie the projects (modules) closely together in this way, but it I understood you correctly, they are already tightly interrelated.